# Azure logic apps http connector for ADLS is corrupting the zip file

Tags: azure-logic-apps, outlook-restapi, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using the Azure logic-apps to get the Attachments from an email (outlook) and dump into the Azure Datalake Gen2. I am using the http connector to dump the file into the adls.
Though I am able to dump the file into the datalake but this zip file is getting corrupted.
Previously I had Azure datalake Gen1 so I was using the adls `Upload File` action to upload the attachment then I didn't face such type of issue.
I am not sure whether I am committing mistake or is there issue with the http connector.
Hence seeking help from the community.
[image: HTTP connector screenshot1]
[image: HTTP connector screenshot2]

I am also attaching the part of the logic apps flow:
[image: LA flow part1]
[image: LA flow part2]

Comment: Could you please provide us with screenshots of the design process of your logic app. Thanks!

Comment: You should prefer to use inbuilt connectors only in Logic Apps, maybe you are missing something in Http Connector which ADLS connector is correctly doing.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT added the flow screenshot

Comment: @FrankGong shared the screenshots

Comment: @Stark According to your screenshot, you upload zip file to azure blob.

Comment: @JimXu I am uploading zip file to the adls gen2. In adls gen2 storage type is blob type.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use inbuilt connectors in Logic App.

For Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (ADLS Gen2) accounts, you can use Azure Blob Storage connector (recommended by Microsoft), while having [multi-protocol access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access). You can read more about this new feature, including the availability and known limitations in this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/silo-busting-2-0-multi-protocol-access-for-azure-data-lake-storage/).

**Known issues and limitations**:

- The action **Extract archive to folder** ignores empty files and folders in the archive, they are not extracted to the destination.
- The trigger does not fire if a file is added/updated in a subfolder. If it is required to trigger on subfolders, multiple triggers should be created.
- Logic apps can't directly access storage accounts that are behind firewalls if they're both in the same region. As a workaround, you can have your logic apps and storage account in different regions. For more information about enabling access from Azure Logic Apps to storage accounts behind firewalls, see the [Access storage accounts behind firewalls.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#access-storage-accounts-behind-firewalls)

For more information about this, you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#azure-data-lake-storage-gen2).